# mysql optimization with multiple left joins, group by and order

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm experiencing some difficulties with my queries which contains multiple left joins in combination with a group by and order.

Text table and textdetails contain +- 800k records
Copy table and copydetails contain +- 200k records
Other tables are a lot smaller.

I have foreign keys for every column I perform a left join on.
I also have indexes on every column on which I perform a where statement.
Still the MySQL query below runs approx 40 seconds.
Leaving out the Group By improves a bit.
Leaving out the Order By improves a lot.

I did some research but I'm still confused on how to improve my query or indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM `copy` 
LEFT JOIN `domain` ON domain.domain_id = copy.copy_domain_id 
LEFT JOIN `domaincategory` ON copy.copy_domain_id = domaincategory.domaincategory_domain_id AND domaincategory.domaincategory_account_id = copy.copy_account_id 
LEFT JOIN `text` ON text.text_id = copy.copy_text_id LEFT JOIN `textdetails` ON textdetails.textdetails_text_id = text.text_id 
LEFT JOIN `channel` ON channel.channel_domain_id = domain.domain_id AND channel.channel_account_id = copy.copy_account_id 
LEFT JOIN `feed` ON feed.feed_id = text.text_feed_id 
WHERE (feed.feed_account_id = 96) AND (feed.feed_flag_delete IS NULL) AND (text.text_flag_delete IS NULL) AND (copy.copy_flag_delete IS NULL) AND (copy.copy_tracking_date_found IS NOT NULL) AND (channel.channel_active = 1) 
GROUP BY `copy`.`copy_id`
ORDER BY `copy`.`copy_tracking_date_found` DESC LIMIT 50
```

The result of the EXPLAIN option is shown below but I can't figure out how to read it and use it properly

```
ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : Feed
Type : Ref
Possible_Keys: PRIMARY,fk_feed_account_id,feed_flag_delete
Key: fk_feed_account_id
Key_len : 4:
Ref : const
Rows : 1
Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : text
Type : Ref
Possible_Keys: PRIMARY,fk_text_feed_id,text_flag_delete
Key: text_flag_delete
Key_len : 2
Ref : const
Rows : 2628
Extra: Using where


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : textdetails
Type : Ref
Possible_Keys: fk_textdetails_text_id
Key: fk_textdetails_text_id
Key_len : 5
Ref : text.text_id
Rows : 1
Extra:


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : copy
Type : Ref
Possible_Keys: fk_copy_account_id,fk_copy_domain_id,fk_copy_text_...
Key: fk_copy_text_id
Key_len : 4
Ref : text.text_id
Rows : 1
Extra: Using where


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : domain
Type : eq_ref
Possible_Keys: PRIMARY
Key: PRIMARY
Key_len : 4
Ref : copy.copy_domain_id
Rows : 1
Extra: Using where


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : domaincategory
Type : eq_ref
Possible_Keys: fk_domaincategory_account_id,fk_domaincategory_dom
Key: fk_domaincategory_domain_id
Key_len : 4
Ref : domain.domain_id
Rows : 1
Extra:


ID  : 1
Select_type : SIMPLE
Table : channel
Type : ref
Possible_Keys: fk_channel_account_id,fk_channel_domain_id,channel...
Key: fk_channel_domain_id
Key_len : 4
Ref : copy.copy_domain_id
Rows : 2
Extra: Using where
```

Perhaps I should explain the relations a little bit more?
    feed : text = 1:n
    text : textdetails  = 1:1
    text : copy = 1:n
    copy : domain = n:1
    channel : domain n:1

Comment: You need to have MySQL explain what the query is doing:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and post them?

Comment: I just did. Can't seem to figure out how to read the EXPLAIN function properly

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few things I would change and have updated the query to reflect that.  Also, for indexes.  If you have indexes on every column, but they are individual indexes, that WONT necessarily help you.  You need compound (multiple field) indexes to better match your join / where criteria and groupings if possible.

```
SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
      feed f 
         JOIN text t
            ON feed.feed_id = t.text_feed_id
            LEFT JOIN textdetails td 
               ON t.text_id = td.textdetails_text_id 
            JOIN COPY c
               ON t.text_id = c.copy_text_id 
               LEFT JOIN domain d
                  ON c.copy_domain_id = d.domain_id
               LEFT JOIN domaincategory dc 
                  ON  c.copy_domain_id = dc.domaincategory_domain_id 
                  AND c.copy_account_id = cd.domaincategory_account_id
               JOIN channel ch 
                  ON  c.copy_account_id = ch.channel_account_id 
                  AND c.copy_domain_id = ch.channel_domain_id
                  AND ch.channel_active = 1
   WHERE 
          f.feed_account_id = 96
      AND f.feed_flag_delete IS NULL
      AND t.text_flag_delete IS NULL
      AND c.copy_flag_delete IS NULL
      AND c.copy_tracking_date_found IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY 
      c.copy_id
   ORDER BY 
      c.copy_tracking_date_found DESC 
   LIMIT 
      50
```

[Transitive Property](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property.htm)
Since copy.copy_domain_id is a join to domain.domain_id and channel.channel_domain_id is joined to domain.domain_id, we can just change to copy.copy_domain_id = channel.channel_domain_id and not require a split join to different tables on the otherwise same value.

Second... you have LEFT JOINS, but when you add "feed_account_id = 96", you are automatically converting that into an INNER JOIN as it is a requirement, thus making the TEXT alias a join as well.  Similarly with the CHANNEL table having Channel_Active = 1.  (I have update query to reflect that).

Now, since qualifying based on the FEED table for a specific account, I have moved that into the first FROM position and joining down to the Copy table.

Now, indexes to help optimize this

```
table        index
feed         ( feed_account_id, feed_id, feed_flag_delete )
text         ( text_feed_id, text_id, text_flag_delete )
textdetails  ( textdetails_text_id )
copy         ( copy_text_id, copy_domain_id, copy_account_id, copy_flag_delete, copy_tracking_date_found, copy_id )
domain       ( domain_id )
domaincategory ( domaincategory_domain_id, domaincategory_account_id )
channel       ( channel_domain_id, channel_account_id, channel_active )
```

Comment: Thanks DRapp for your extensive explanation.  
I'm trying to figure it all out.  
I've implemented your solution and tried it for 2 accounts  
- the first account has 1 feed, 40k text_id's en 10k copy_id's  
- the second account has 5 feeds, 70k text_id's en 150k copy_id's  

For the first account the query took roughly 1 sec.  
For the second account the query still took 40+ sec.

Comment: @quibuz, One more option...  add one keyword...  SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... the STRAIGHT_JOIN keyword tells the engine to run as I have it listed.  See how that works, and also... how many records ARE being returned in the second account's result set.  The other issue is doing SELECT * is crazy and gets all fields from all tables.  You really should try and avoid that and get what you NEED, not just everything because its there.  Let me know how STRAIGHT_JOIN works for you and time / records.